# SELinux prevents an android app from reading a serial device file

Tags: android, device-driver, selinux, cdc

I am using a Galaxy S5 (G900H) and I am connecting a serial device to it via USB using cdc-acm driver and trying to read it from my android application.
It works fine on other devices (older and newer).

When connecting the device, the device file `/dev/ttyACM0` is created but when trying to read from it I receive an error `Permission denied`.
When running `setenforce 0` and setting SELinux to Permissive mode - everything works fine and the app reads the device file successfully.

The dmesg says:

```
cdc_acm 2-1:1.0: usb_probe_interface
cdc_acm 2-1:1.0: usb_probe_interface
cdc_acm 2-1:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
cdc_acm 2-1:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

I tried making a new policy using audit2allow but couldn't find any "denied" message to use in order to create an "allow" rule.

Is there any way to use the device file via my app without setting SELinux to permissive? I can edit the kernel and make a new one if needed, but I really prefer not to.

Thanks!